# Unity displaying message "the associated script cannot be loaded" for all scripts when restarted

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am following the Sebastian Lague procedural planet tutorial, and am on episode 3. Unity started refusing to refresh scripts and not showing any changes made, with no error messages. When I re-opened the project, all scripts displayed the message "The associated script cannot be loaded. Please fix any compile errors or assign a valid script." All scripts, when selected, show a message saying that they have "no MonoBehaviour Scripts" , even if they had. This problem persisted through:

- Restarting Unity
- creating a new project and adding the Tutorial's assets
- Reimporting all

I could not find any fixes that worked on StackOverflow.
the Code is in the E02 folder on https://github.com/SebLague/Procedural-Planets.

This is my first time using unity, so I'm not sure whether the problem is with the code, something I've done on unity, or just a bug in the Unity software.

Answer (score 0):

The error message says it all: "... Please fix any compile errors or assign a valid script."

Please check your console, maybe displaying errors is turned off

Comment: Sorry, this is my first time using unity; where would I find the setting to turn that back on?

Comment: This worked  - a missing semicolon had broken everything somehow. Thanks!